# Renaming chapter folder and referring to images efficiently

Tags: graphics

I need some advice on organizing files for my dissertation. I am writing various chapters of my dissertation based on my published papers and a number of chapters are quite image heavy. I have created folders for each chapter and inside each chapter I have a folder named "figures" where I keep figures(EPS, PNG and FIG) related to that chapter.

Because the figures folder is inside the chapter, I had to use following command to display the image:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{Chapter_8/Figures/EPS/AndersonTanker/AndersonTanker_Pitch_Fn0_Beta180}
```

The only problem is having the "Chapter_8/" in the file path. Whenever I need to change the order of chapters, I had to manually rename the path for each figure (find+replace of course).

Has anyone faced the same problem? I don't want to keep all my figures for the whole dissertation in one folder.

Please let me know if there is any easy solution to this. Thanks inadvance.

Comment: There is a reason why calling a chapter by its content is recommended, not by number. Just name your folders `intro` and `exprerimental` and `bigExplosion` and `aftermath` or something similar. You know what you are writing about, i don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{AndersonTanker_Pitch_Fn0_Beta180}
```

and arrange that your TEXINPUTS path includes `.//` then any tex or image file in any directory below the directory with your main document will be found.